# What is the best approach for locking sql row?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have below table employee

```
id  name  age
```

What is the difference between the below sql select

```
1. SELECT id FROM employee WHERE id=1 FOR UPDATE

2. SELECT * FROM employee WHERE id=1 FOR UPDATE
```

Which query we should follow to lock the row?

Comment: Why do we need to lock the row?

Comment: I want to lock the row for update

Comment: Both queries will lock all rows of the `employee` table, which is probably not good for database performance. The only difference is whether you get only the `id` column or all columns. More context would help us understand.

Comment: i have updated the question, please check. Just want to understand keeping * or id does it make any difference in performance  ?

Comment: @Jax Either will lock the row. Otherwise treat it as a regular `select` and only select the rows you need. If you don't need any rows, `select 1`. But usually you want to lock a row because you're going to update based on the data you just read.

Comment: So if my understanding is correct it doesnt make any difference on locking if we take **select * or select id** correct?

Comment: *What is the difference between the below sql select* From the point of view of blocking records, there is no difference.

Comment: But really - don't. Find another pattern. Much better to check for an update since your last read, and action accordingly. And use transactions which will probably get around most of your problems.